# MySQL - Duplicated values in auto-incremented field

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a partitioned InnoDB table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `actions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `⁯id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`⁯id_user`),
  KEY `⁯id_user` (`⁯id_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (⁯id_user)
(PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (100000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (200000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN (300000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

There are inserts and updates in the tens of thousands per minute on this table.
From time to time, I'm getting duplicated values in the `id`, which is an auto-increment field.
Inserts don't have an `id` specified. There could be a single row inserted or multiple rows at once.
I'm using MySQL 5.7.26 and there's replication involved but there was no restart when this happened and all the inserts are made on the same server.

These are some of the settings:

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode 1
auto_increment_increment 1
```

Is there a way to avoid this from happening?

Comment: How about transactions?

Comment: There have been bugs reported about duplicate AI values. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76872 is fixed in versions 5.6.35, 5.7.17, 8.0.1, if you are using versions prior to these (in the respective branch), then upgrade.

Comment: Another bug was opened about duplicate AI values, and there is no fix yet. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88321 is verified in versions 5.6.35, 5.7.20, 8.0.12. If the test case in that bug matches your usage, you should click the "Affects Me" button on that bug.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks. The version I'm using is 5.7.26. I'll update the question

Comment: Keep in mind that even auto increment columns could be overridden by explicit values on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements. My recommendation is making `id` unique if that is possible for you.

Comment: What are your settings for `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` and `auto_increment_increment`?

Comment: Is replication involved?  Did you restart the server recently?  Is a "cluster" involved?  What do your `INSERTs` look like?

Comment: @RickJames Single row and multiple rows. (added more info to the question)

Comment: @BillKarwin 1 and 1.

Comment: @Kalecser Tried it but it's not allowed: `A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

Comment: I'm leaning toward it being a `PARTITIONing` bug.  Do you have a self-contained test case?  Also, does it happen with a single connection running all the `INSERTs`?  Or does it only happen with multiple connections doing "simultaneous" `INSERTs`?

Comment: And... is it just dup AI values?  Or is the pair `(id, id_user)` showing duplicates?

Comment: @RickJames Just the AI.

Comment: @RickJames And it's definitely happening with multiple connections. I've never found a case where the duplicated values were generated when inserts were made by a single connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`⁯id_user`)
```

Says that the *pair* of columns is unique.

It *does* allow there to be duplicates in `id`.  However this rarely happens, since users *usually* don't specify a value for auto_inc column when `INSERTing`.

(This is another drawback of `PARTITIONs`.)

Show us a sample of your `INSERT`.

Comment: Updated the question.